# Regular expression that matches Chinese word excluding other words at beginning and ending of matched word

Tags: python, python-re, cjk

I would like to find the right regular expression that matches a single Chinese word in a Chinese sentence. For example:

`[^大小]堆[^積疊]|[^大]堆$|^堆[^積]`

- 大堆   --> not matching
- 稚積   --> not matching
- 中堆   --> matches 堆
- 堆上   --> matches 堆
- 一堆三 --> matches 堆

I know my regular expression is wrong, how to write the correct and terse regular expression?

Thanks

Comment: Show some code and effort please!  :)

Comment: "(?!堆[積疊])(?＜![一大])堆"